# Reassigning awk array during loop

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

My problem is the following: 
I had a text file formatted in a way:

```
12 apple 
78 orange 
12 prune
12 prune
78 berries
78 cake
```

What I needed is to reassign the values in a form:

```
12 apple, prune
78 orange, berries, cake
```

I did it using awk `{sbj=$2","; a[$1]=a[$1]sbj}END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}`
But the problem is that now I have the file, formatted as:

```
12 apple one
78 orange one

12 prune two
12 prune two
78 berries two
78 cake two
```

And the desire output is :

```
12 apple one
78 orange one

12 prune two
78 berries, cake two
```

I was trying to do it mixing awk and bash, but it didn't help. The only option I can do now is to store each series ("one", "two") into separate files and treat them separately with the above code, then sum up all the arrays into a file. But it's ponderous and clumsy solution. Is there any option to make it in the same file?
Thank you for any tips.

Comment: It was me, too stupid to get the question in the first place. ;) (Also the output for the first example isn't completely right, that confused me). Was busy with answering then, but now reverted the close vote.

Comment: What's wrong with the output for the first example? It looks right to me.

Comment: If you try the given code snippet it will be `12 apple, prune prune` instead of `12 apple prune` That confused me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF {
    if (!seen[$1,$2]++) {
        arr[$1] = ($1 in arr ? arr[$1] "," OFS : "") $2
        sfx[$1] = $3
    }
    next
}
{ prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt(   i) {
    for (i in arr) {
        print i, arr[i], sfx[i]
    }
    print ""
    delete sfx
    delete arr
    delete seen
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
12 apple one
78 orange one

12 prune two
78 berries, cake two
```

Note that the above will print the output lines in random order courtesy of the `in` operator - if you want to retain the original input order then you'd need an extra step when saving the values. It will however print the blocks and the $2 values in the same order they appear in the input.

Comment: The reported output is not completely honest, it will print and additional empty line at the end. ;) I like the `NF {}` part, better than `!NF{next}` but I'll keep it now as it is.

Comment: Since the site won't show a blank line at the end of a formatted code/text snippet, we don't know if one's present in the OPs desired output or not. I choose to think it is :-). I did have a bug though where I was printing "prune" twice for the 2nd block, I've fixed that now.

Comment: Ed Morton, thank you for your answer. If I may ask,  could you please explain the meaning of "NF" sign at the beginning of the code and the "!seen[$1,$2]++" statement. Because I didn't get how can it work, if  we do the 'next' statement: thus, as I understand from the UserManual, the "next" statement should create an array until it reachs the end of the file, so in the output it should be " 12 apple, prune, prune \n 78 orange, berries, cake" ?

Comment: `NF` is the awk variable that contains the number of fields in the current line. When the line is empty NF is zero. So `NF { action }` only executes `action` when the current line is not empty. So in the above code we keep populating the arrays on non-empty lines and when we hit an empty line then `NF` is false so we don't perform the action (which includes `next` in our code) and so we move onto the next block which prints and then clears out the arrays. Read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn awk.

Comment: Now its clear for me. Thank you for the answer and for the suggested book!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk you can use multidimensional arrays:

*foo.awk:*

```
!NF{next} # Skip empty lines
{a[$3][$1]=a[$3][$1]" "$2}
END{
    for(i in a){
        for(ii in a[i]){
            print ii" "a[i][ii]" "i
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Run it like:

```
gawk -f foo.awk input.file
```

---

I need to mention that there is one drawback with the above solution besides that it works only with `gawk`: The output is not guaranteed to be in order. That's because `for(i in a)` doesn't guarantee any order by default. `gawk` supports a special array variable `PROCINFO` that can be used to enforce individual sorting of arrays:

*foo.awk:*

```
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
}
!NF{next} # Skip empty lines
{a[$3][$1]=a[$3][$1]" "$2}
END{
    for(i in a){
        for(ii in a[i]){
            print ii" "a[i][ii]" "i
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You should mention that that will produce the output in random/hash order (e.g. it can print the 2nd block before the first block, and the lines from each block in any order) as when the OP tries it on his small input set he may get the output in the same order it appeared in the input and think that's guaranteed to occur.

Comment: hek2mgl, thank you for the introduction to multidimensional arrays, it was new for me.

Comment: You are welcome. I've added some sentences about ordering the output. For a stable, predictable solution you should follow that.